# Thymeleaf Get data from Html

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I need get data from html to controller with press button also Html data as list.

```
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Company Name</th>
            <th>Book Name</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Order</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr th:each="Books: ${Books }">
            <td th:text="${Books.CompanyName}" />
            <td th:text="${Books.BookName}" />
            <td th:text="${Books.AuthorName}" />
            <td th:text="${Books.Price}" />
            <td th:button class="Order-Button" type="button" >Order</button> </td>
```

Also this is my Controller

```
@Autowired
    private BookRep bookRep;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/BookOrder")
    ModelAndView submitBookOrder(){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("BookOrder");
        mav.addObject("Books", bookRep.findAll());
        return mav;

    }
```

My expect to when user press take order button it will get row datas in controller

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wrote demo code for you. I think it will be useful for you. You can understand what you want by looking at the code

```
@GetMapping("/Books/{id}")
public String books(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model){

    model.addAttribute("Books", bookService.getById(id));

    return "book-list";
}
```

<-td> <-a th:href="@{/Books/{id}(id = ${book.id})}">
<-button type="submit" class="btn btn-info col-2" style="min-width: fit-content">  Books List<-/button>

Comment: What is bookService ?

Comment: Are you trying to show HTML tags by adding `-` into the tags - for example `<-td>` instead of `<td>`? Instead of doing that, you can look at how to [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) content. You can format your HTML the same way you formatted your Java (and there are other ways also).